# If statement doesn't hit certain conditions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I'm currently working on a very simple(first project) market in solidity and i'm having an issue with a piece of code :

```
  contract smallMarket{

    struct transaction {
      uint timeStamp;
      uint qtyT;
      uint price;
      address client;
      bytes32 typee;
    }
    struct sellOrder {
      uint timeStamp;
      uint qty;
      uint price;
      address seller;
    }

    mapping(uint => transaction) public transactions;
    mapping(uint => sellOrder) public sellorders;

    uint public lastTransactionId;
    uint public lastBOrderId;
    uint public lastSOrderId;
    address public owner;

    function smallMarket(){
      owner = msg.sender;
      lastSOrderId = 0;
    }
    function newTransaction(uint amount,uint price,bytes32 typee){
      uint transac = lastTransactionId + 1;
      transaction t = transactions[transac];
      t.timeStamp = block.timestamp;
      t.qtyT = amount;
      t.price = price;
      t.client = msg.sender;
      t.typee = typee;
      lastTransactionId = transac; 
    }

    function newSellOrder(uint amount,uint price,uint currency) {
        uint order = lastSOrderId + 1; 
        sellOrder s = sellorders[order];
        s.timeStamp = block.timestamp;
        s.qty = amount;
        s.price = price;
        s.seller = msg.sender;
        lastSOrderId = order;
    }
    function buy(uint amount, uint price) {
      uint idCounter = lastSOrderId;
      uint _amountLeftToBuy = amount;
      while (_amountLeftToBuy > 0){
          if (price >= sellorders[idCounter].price && sellorders[idCounter].qty >= amount) {
            newTransaction(amount,price,'cas 1');
            _amountLeftToBuy = 0;

          }
          else if (price >= sellorders[idCounter].price && amount > sellorders[idCounter].qty ){
              newTransaction(amount,price,'cas 2');
              _amountLeftToBuy =  amount - sellorders[idCounter].qty;
              idCounter = idCounter - 1;
          }
          else if (sellorders[idCounter].price > price){
              newTransaction(amount,price,'cas 3');
              _amountLeftToBuy = 0;
          }
          else{}
      }    
    }
  }
```

I'm manually creating a sellorder struct for testing purpose and it fails on the buy function.

Manually create SO:

```
newSellOrder(5,200,1)  #=> (uint amount,uint price,uint currency)
```

Then calling buy function with different cases:

```
buy(6,201)  #=>(uint amount, uint price)
buy(4,201)
buy(4,199)
```

In my Buy function , there are 3 case :

`price >= sellorders[idCounter].price && sellorders[idCounter].qty >= amount`

Should work with => buy(4,201)

`price >= sellorders[idCounter].price && amount > sellorders[idCounter].qty`

=>buy(6,201)

`sellorders[idCounter].price > price`

=>buy(4,199)

My issue is that for some reason the cause #2 ( buy(6,201) ) never get triggered.( so only 2 transaction are created instead of 3)

Anybody see what i'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

So, after hours of debugging :

My iteration was wrong i wasn't referring to _amountLeftToBuy in my conditional but to amount.

Comment: Could you add some more details to your answer and how you solved the issue? Maybe somebody else has that same issue one day.